# Delimiter doesn't work with UDP

Tags: udp, netty, delimiter

My program listen to incoming message using TCP.
In order to support incoming of multiple messages, separated by new line delimiter, I'm adding the following at the beginning of the pipeline –

```
New DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(256, Delimiters.lineDelimiter())
```

The above is working great with TCP. Multiple messages are separated as expected.

The problem is that the code doesn't work with UDP.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TCP** is a connection oriented stream over an IP network. It guarantees that all sent packets will reach the destination in the correct order. **UDP** Communication is datagram oriented, this datagrams reach destination and can arrive *out of order or don't arrive at all*. I think that is you problem.